# I can't upgrade my windows 8 enterprise to windows 8.1 Enteprise preview

Tags: windows-8.1-preview

My PC is running Windows 8 Enterprise X64 (French).
I'm trying to upgrade to 8.1 preview, so I downloaded the 64 bits ISO of Windows 8.1 preview (french):`fr_windows_8.1_preview_x64_dvd_2358804.iso`

My I start the setup from the media, the setup does not propose me to upgrade and keep my applications.
Only `Keep personal files only` and `Keep nothing` are available.

When I read the technet page [Supported Upgrade Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx#EightOne), upgrading and keeping everything should be proposed.

Why can't I upgrade? Do I missed something?

Comment: Because what you downloaded wasn't the Windos 8.1 Enterprise Preview.

Comment: @Ramhound: Where can I find the enterprise preview? I also tried WindowsBlue-ClientwithApps-64bit-French-X1899615.iso... but I get the same behavior.

Comment: Moreover, I can read [Enterprise and volume license users: If you're running Windows 8 Enterprise or the Windows 8 Enterprise Evaluation on your PC, you'll need to download the Windows 8.1 Preview ISO files.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-download). So I followed the link and download the formerly named iso file (WindowsBlue-ClientwithApps-64bit-French-X1899615.iso)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8.1 Enterprise has not been released yet.  Its not expected until later this month.

[Source](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2013/06/27/windows-8-1-preview-an-enterprise-call-to-action.aspx)

### Computers running Windows 8 Enterprise

> Wait for the availability of the Windows 8.1 Enterprise Preview ISO,
>   which should be available in the coming weeks. Watch for an
>   announcement on this blog when it is available.

Answer (score 1):

On any Windows platform, you cannot go from Windows Enterprise to any other platform by doing an installation update. You will have do a clean install. Windows 8.1 Enterprise Preview is not available in the Windows Store, or Windows Site for download. We are all waiting for that particular release.

Comment: On one of my computers, I choose this path to solve my issue. No as simple as I thought (long install, have to reinstall some apps, ...)/ But this worked. For production computers, I'll wait a Enterprise edition of the update (or even the RTM version)